# Width to fit any value of an unsigned (natural) number

Tags: c++, c++14

## Background

I have a logging system that outputs records to a `std::ostream`. Each record is annotated with a counter that is increased by one with each output, like this:

```
=====  Batch # 5  =====
  This is the fifth record
=====  Batch # 19  =====
  This is the nineteenth record
=====  Batch # 187  =====
  Who knows to spell *that*?
```

The counter is a [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), i.e., an unsigned integer.

## Problem

As it is now, numbers are outputted without any padding, which looks ugly. I would like to achieve this:

```
=====  Batch #     5  =====
  This is the fifth record
=====  Batch #    19  =====
  ...
=====  Batch #   187  =====
=====  Batch # 12345  =====
```

Making the stream object handle this can be achieved with [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw). However, I still need to know how many digits takes the base-10 representation of the maximum possible value.

## Request

The solution must compute statically (i.e. at translation-time) how many digits takes the base-10 representation of the maximum possible value of a `std::size_t`. I will welcome any method that meets this requirement, although I will prefer those that employ C++14's (relaxed) `constexpr`s.

### Hints and things I have tried

It seems that the representation of a natural number N in base-B takes as many digits as the truncation of (the B-index logarithm of N) plus 1. For example, the value 100 is three digits long in base 10, and the [common logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm) of 100 plus 1 is 3; the value 1234 is four digits long in base 10, and the truncation of (the common logarithm of 1234) plus 1 is 4. In pseudo-something:

`digits( value , base ) = floor( logarithm( radicand=value , index=base ) ) + 1`

I apologize for the lazyness of the explanation and the formatting; if someone knows a better way, please, feel free to edit my post or to suggest it. You can try this [here](http://web2.0calc.com/). It seems to work, but I haven't thoroughly verified it.

As for the maximum value a `std::size_t` object can hold, it is `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`.

---

I intend to answer this question. I will give some time before posting my answer, and wait more before accepting any.

Comment: Are you really going to have 2^64 batches? How many universe's lifetimes worth of computing are you going to do? Why not just pick a sensible value like 10 or 15 or so.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's just a fixation for doing things 'right'. The background is provided to better explain the question, which is purely theoretical. I agree with you that anyone pragmatic would just choose some good value.

Comment: Why not just see how many times you can divide the max value of size_t. That will be constexpr in C++14. Though, it seems that the answer from ForEveR is better.

Comment: @kec You are right, that would be way simpler! I think it could even be implemented using recursion, if one were to write in C++11. However, the `std::numeric_limits` solution is still much easier :).

Comment: Though, if this is just an academic question, if you want a short, fun exercise, try writing a function to convert int to ASCII. It's not hard, and you can even do it recursively to make it even more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ Standard Library provides the [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) class template, which may be used to query various properties of arithmetic types. Among them is the number of base-10 digits that can be represented by each type, which is encoded in the [`digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) static member, a `constexpr int`. However, and as outlined by Martin Ba in his comments, it is necessary to add 1. Do this:

```
template<class T>
constexpr int maximum_base10_digits =
    std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10 + 1;
```

It will also ensure that the value is computed at translation-time (if you simply pass the value to, say, `std::setw`, the addition could be performed at runtime... a terrible slowdown!).

Although [the corresponding `cppreference.com` page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) does not list any specialization for `std::size_t`, it is not a problem, as stood out in [the `std::numeric_limits` page linked above](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits):

> The standard library types that are aliases of arithmetic types (such
>   as `std::size_t` or `std::streamsize`) may also be examined with the
>   `std::numeric_limits` type traits.

Additionally, this approach has been available since C++11 (or C++98, if you are willing to drop the `constexpr`), which makes it compatible with many more C++ implementations. Just don't make it a variable template if there's no C++14.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>


namespace
{
    template<typename T>
    void
    pretty_print
    (
     const T value
    )
    {
        // Ensure that it's computed at compile-time
        constexpr int maximum_digits = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10 + 1;

        std::cout << std::setw( maximum_digits ) << value << '\n';
    }
}

int
main
( )
{
    pretty_print( std::size_t{ 7 } );
    pretty_print( std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() );
}
```

As a side note, do not get confused with the C++11 addition [`std::numeric_limits::max_digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458355/what-is-the-purpose-of-max-digits10-and-how-is-it-differend-from-digits10)). If you have a look at the list of specializations provided by the Standard Library, you'll note that its value is 0 for all integer types.

Answer (score 7):

Seems that [std::numeric_limits::digits10](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) is what you want.
[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/861c4f4f784ab846)

Comment: Are you sure? The description on cppref makes it unclear to me whether it would report `10` (for the max case) or `9` (for the all fits case) for a 32bit integer -- and indeed [it returns 9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eab6ab47374bebf) but the question would need 10 to accomodate all numbers.

Comment: SO for all types (which would be all) where `max()` isn't a `...9999` value, you need to add 1 to `digits10` I think.

Comment: @MartinBa: Then just add 1 to it.