# What's the meaning of precision digits in float / double / decimal?

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, ieee-754

On the [C# reference for floating-point numeric types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) one can read that

- `float` has a precision of 6 to 9 digits
- `double` has a precision of 15 to 17 digits
- `decimal` has a precision of 28 to 29 digits

What does `precision` mean in this context and especially, how can the `precision` be a range? As the number of bits for the exponent and mantissa are fixed, how can the `precision` be variable (in the described range)? Can someone please give an example for e.g. a `float` with a `precision` of 6 and one with a `precision` of 9?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [System.Double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)?

Comment: See https://blog.demofox.org/2017/11/21/floating-point-precision/

Comment: I'm also going to close to that duplicate, but will add `decimal` is indeed floating point.  However it is base 10, not base 2 (like float and double)

Comment: @Zer0 My question is not about float vs. double but about variable precision in each of these types. xanatos explained it very well in his answer.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'll vote to reopen.  Seeing decimal in there threw me way off, apologies.  While decimal is floating point, it's not what we commonly consider floating point (base 2 floating point).  However maybe it's the wrong dupe?  I'd be surprised if this wasn't answered before.

Comment: I can suggest even the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: @xanatos In my opinion you should really restore your answer as it was easy and fast to understand.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Rechek now.

Comment: @Zer0 As for decimal, close but not quite.  Decimal is referred to as fixed point, not floating point like the other two. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7524838/15880

Comment: @Powerlord I'll look at the actual implementation in a bit, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0) states it is floating-point.  And I agree.

Comment: @Powerlord.  Code shows [decimal](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/decimal.cs) is [floating point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) (however, it is base 10).  I find this to be a common misconception in C#.  Likely due to so much hardware being optimized for float and double (base 2 floating point).

Answer (score 2):

## float and double

(I'll explain `float`, that is [IEEE-754 Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), but `double`, that is [IEEE-754 Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is the same but with bigger numbers.

In general you can imagine a `float` to be:

> mantissa₂ * (2 ^ exponent₂)

where mantissa₂ means mantissa in base two, and exponent₂ means exponent in base two

The mantissa₂ is 23 bits, the exponent₂ 8 bits. There is an extra bit for the sign, and the exponent₂ has a special format with special range that we will see much below

There is another trick: floating points are normally saved in "normalized" form:

> 1₂ mantissa₂ * (2 ^ exponent₂)

so the first digit is always 1₂, and so there is a 1₂ plus 23 binary digits for the mantissa₂, so a total of 24 digits for the complete mantissa₂.

Now, with 24 bits you can have numbers between 0 and 16,777,216, that is 7 full digits plus the 8th that is "partial" (you can't have 26,777,216 for example). In fact log₁₀ 2^24 = 7.22471989594

The exponent "moves" a floating decimal point, so that you can have, for example

> 1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂ . 1₂ (there are a total of 24 binary digits 1, I hope... I counted them)

or

> 1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂ . 1₂1₂

or

> 1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂0₂

or

> 1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂1₂0₂0₂

and so on.

The exponent₂ has three ranges: `[-1;-127]`, `[1;127]`, `0` for denormalized numbers and `255` for NaN and Infinite (where `255` means that all the bits of the exponent are at `1`)

In the range `[-1;-127]` the decimal point is moved to the left, for a number of steps equal to the range, in the range [1;127]` the decimal point is moved to the right in the same way.

If the exponent is `0`, the number is "denormalized". They are ugly floating point numbers that have special handling and are slower for this reason. When the number is "denormalized" then there is no implicit 1₂ at the beginning of the number, so you only have 23 bits of mantissa, that is 6 dot something digits of precision (log₁₀ 2^23 = 6.9236899)

Can't explain how the 9 digits of precision come out.

## decimal

With [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0) it is easy: the format is:

> mantissa₂ / (10 ^ exponent₂)

where mantissa₂ is 96 bits, exponent₂ is 5 bits (a little less, the range is `[0;28]`), plus there is a sign bit, and many unused bits. The exact format is written in the [reference source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/decimal.cs#L134). In `decimal`s there is no implicit initial 1₂, so it is pure 96 bits, and log₁₀ 2^96 = 28.8988795837, so 28 or 29 digits.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the meaning of precision digits in float / double / decimal?

The *decimal* digits needed to *round trip* between text and the type.

text-FP-text: When a number is decimal text and then converted to floating point type and then converted back to text with the same number of digits and get the same value, over the entire exponent range of the FP type, the max number of significant decimal digits in the text version is the lower number like 6 for `float`.  As long as the text version has only 6 digits display, `float` can encode a value close enough.

FP-text-FP: When a FP number is converted to decimal text and then converted back to FP and get the same FP value, the number of significant decimal digits needed for the text version is the higher number like 9 for `float`.  As long as a text version reports 9+ significant digits, the original FP value can be recovered exactly.

`float` has 24 bits of *binary* precession.  To translate that into *decimal*, the above context is important.  The minimum non-zero `double` takes about [330+](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212490/function-to-print-a-double-exactly) *decimal* digits to printout exactly, yet that is rarely thought of as the precession of that number.

---

Can someone please give an example for e.g. a float with a precision of 6 and one with a precision of 9?

[6 decimal digits always works .... "9999979e3" and "9999978e3" both convert to 9.999978e+09](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47130842/2410359), so 9 significant text digits needed to round-trip.